# Symfony4: understanding the directory public/bundles

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have a problem with the directory `public/bundles` in my symfony4 project and I am not sure what causes it. I have three dependencies that initial created a symbolic link in this directory. Because I wanted to edit some of the files, I just copied all contents of whatever they were pointing to to the `public/bundles` directory and made my edits. So far so good.

The problem occurs every time I update files on the production environment. Whenever I copy files from my computer (on windows) to my remote production server (on linux), the contents of `public/bundles` are removed and the 'original' symbolic links are reinstated. I then have to remove them and upload specifically all directories from my local pc to the server again and things are good again.

What could cause such behaviour though? Could this have something to do with the software I use to upload files (WinSCP) or are there directory settings somewhere I do not know about? Could this be because of GIT ignoring the files? There was the line `/public/bundles/` in my `.gitignore` file, which I removed, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/public/bundles` is a location for client-side assets of any bundles/packages included in a project. There is a script which fires on `composer install` and *re-installs* symlinks or files. Any deployment scripts should/could refresh those files too. It's intended.

If you would like to override any assets of 3rd-party package, then create a copy outside of `/public/bundles` and update/override twig templates to include new files instead of originals.